# Count no. of tokens in every row of a column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with data in the of similar format

```
    song                    lyric                                tokenized_lyrics
0   Song 1  Look at her face, it's a wonderful face  [look , at , her ,face, it's a wonderful, face ]
1   Song 2  Some lyrics of the song taken            [Some, lyrics ,of, the, song, taken]
```

I want  to count the no of words in the lyrics per song and an output like

```
song     count
song 1     8
song 2     6
```

I tried aggregate  function but it is not yielding the correct result.

Code I tried :

```
df.groupby(['song']).agg(
word_count = pd.NamedAgg(column='text' , aggfunc = 'count' )
)
```

How can I achieve the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) for count values and if duplicated `song` values then aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = (df.assign(count = df['tokenized_lyrics'].str.len())
         .groupby('song', as_index=False)['count'].sum())
```

Answer (score 3):

I couldnt copy tokenized_lyrics as a list, it came in as a string, so I tokenized the lyrics, with the assumption that the delimiter is a white space:

```
df['token_count'] = df.lyric.str.replace(',','').str.split().str.len()
df.filter(['song','token_count'])

    song    token_count
0   Song 1      8
1   Song 2      6
```

note that you can just apply [string len](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) to the tokenized lyrics to get your count, since it is a list, it will count the individual items